# Elastic memory configuration in hazelcast 3.4.1

Tags: hazelcast

Can we still configure elastic memory in hazelcast 3.4.1 ?.

I do see the **NATIVE** Option for Map enabling off heap storage.

Not sure still we can use below properties **hazelcast.elastic.memory.enabled, hazelcast.elastic.memory.total.size** to use the RAM memory instead only heap.
Because Hazelcast version 3.4.1 documentation says that it supports **high density memory datastore** using Jcache.

Is **Highdensity memory datastore** is second generation implementation of elastic memory?

Thanks in advance

Dinesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, HD Memory store is a second generation off-heap memory. We don't call it elastic memory anymore.

You can find configuration for HD memory [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-documentation/src/Storage.md#configuring-hi-density-memory-store) and in [JCache section](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-documentation/src/JCache-JCacheConfiguration.md)

Also, IMap API for off-heap documentation will be available as well. Follow this [issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/4777)